# SharePoint is not picking up email address of a particular user in AD

Tags: user-profile-service

We have a travel request form in SharePoint where two of the fields are "Traveler Name" and "Traveler Email". When the "Traveler Name" is filled up then "Traveler Email" field automatically picks up the email of the traveler. The problem we are having is, the "Traveler Email" field does not pick up the email address of a particular user. For all other users it works fine. We had a problem in the active directory and some other uses also had the same problem. Once we fixed that problem in AD, all the users are doing fine except a particular user. Please help.

Comment: Does that particular user have their email address populated in the AD property?

Comment: @BigRaj Yes, it does

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve this by troubleshooting .

Here's what you can do :-

1. Delete the user profile of the specified user from user profile service application .
2. Remove the user from User information list .
3. Start profile synchronization again and recreate user profile using this.
4. Run crawl after this from Search service application
5. Check if the form is able to populate the email address correctly now .

Let me know in case issues persists.